# Making Categorical or Grouped Bar Graph with secondary Axis Line Graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I need to compare different sets of daily data between 4 shifts(categorical / groupby), using bar graphs and line graphs. I have looked everywhere and have not found a working solution for this that doesn't include generating new pivots and such.

I've used both, matplotlib and seaborn, and while I can do one or the other(different colored bars/lines for each shift), once I incorporate the other, either one disappears, or other anomalies happen like only one plot point shows. I have looked all over and there are solutions for representing a single series of data on both chart types, but none that goes into multi category or grouped for both.

Data Example:

```
report_date wh_id   shift   Head_Count  UTL_R
3/17/19     55  A   72  25%
3/18/19     55  A   71  10%
3/19/19     55  A   76  20%
3/20/19     55  A   59  33%
3/21/19     55  A   65  10%
3/22/19     55  A   54  20%
3/23/19     55  A   66  14%
3/17/19     55  1   11  10%
3/17/19     55  2   27  13%
3/17/19     55  3   18  25%
3/18/19     55  1   23  100%
3/18/19     55  2   16  25%
3/18/19     55  3   12  50%
3/19/19     55  1   28  10%
3/19/19     55  2   23  50%
3/19/19     55  3   14  33%
3/20/19     55  1   29  25%
3/20/19     55  2   29  25%
3/20/19     55  3   10  50%
3/21/19     55  1   17  20%
3/21/19     55  2   29  14%
3/21/19     55  3   30  17%
3/22/19     55  1   12  14%
3/22/19     55  2   10  100%
3/22/19     55  3   17  14%
3/23/19     55  1   16  10%
3/23/19     55  2   11  100%
3/23/19     55  3   13  10%
```

```
tm_daily_df = pd.read_csv('fg_TM_Daily.csv')
tm_daily_df = tm_daily_df.set_index('report_date')
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
ax3 = ax2.twinx()
group_obj = tm_daily_df.groupby('shift')
g = group_obj['Head_Count'].plot(kind='bar', x='report_date',  y='Head_Count',ax=ax2,stacked=False,alpha = .2)
g = group_obj['UTL_R'].plot(kind='line',x='report_date', y='UTL_R', ax=ax3,marker='d', markersize=12)
plt.legend(tm_daily_df['shift'].unique())
```

This code has gotten me the closest I've been able to get. Notice that even with `stacked = False`, they are still stacked. I changed the setting to True, and nothing changes.

All i need is for the bars to be next to each other with the same color scheme representative of the shift

The graph:

[image: graph]

Comment: Thank you for posting on SO and welcome to the site. To make sure I understand your question, you are trying to plot `head_count` as a stacked barchart where each stach represents a shift, and `UTL_R` as a line graph where each line represents a shift?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! I wanted Headcount to be unstacked since I want to compare the headcount each shift had each day(A is for the whole site/all shifts total). Each day needs to have the 4 bars next to each other , but looking at how clean this looks, I would not mind them being stacked(but not whole values on top of each other, instead more like what you see in the picture, each bar is on top of each other starting from the y=0) as long as you can differentiate each shift within the stack, and if they are  by the same colors assigned to the shifts in the line graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions (stacked and unstacked). Based on your questions we will:

- plot `Head_Count` in the left y axis and `UTL_R` in the right y axis.
- `report_date` will be our x axis
- `shift` will represent the hue of our graph.

The stacked version uses `pandas` default plotting feature, and the unstacked version uses `seaborn`.

**EDIT**
From your request, I added a 100% stacked graph. While it is not quite exactly what you asked in the comment, the graph type you asked may create some confusion when reading (are the values based on the upper line of the stack or the width of the stack). An alternative solution may be using a 100% stacked graph.

**Stacked**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dfg = df.set_index(['report_date', 'shift']).sort_index(level=[0,1])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))

ax2  = ax.twinx()

dfg['Head_Count'].unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax, alpha=0.6)
dfg['UTL_R'].unstack().plot(kind='line', ax=ax2, marker='o', legend=None)

ax.set_title('My Graph')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Stacked 100%**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dfg = df.set_index(['report_date', 'shift']).sort_index(level=[0,1])

# Create `Head_Count_Pct` column
for date in dfg.index.get_level_values('report_date').unique():
    for shift in dfg.loc[date, :].index.get_level_values('shift').unique():
        dfg.loc[(date, shift), 'Head_Count_Pct'] = dfg.loc[(date, shift), 'Head_Count'].sum() / dfg.loc[(date, 'A'), 'Head_Count'].sum()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))

ax2  = ax.twinx()
pal = sns.color_palette("Set1")

dfg[dfg.index.get_level_values('shift').isin(['1','2','3'])]['Head_Count_Pct'].unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax, alpha=0.5, color=pal)
dfg['UTL_R'].unstack().plot(kind='line', ax=ax2, marker='o', legend=None, color=pal)

ax.set_title('My Graph')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Unstacked**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dfg = df.set_index(['report_date', 'shift']).sort_index(level=[0,1])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,6))

ax2  = ax.twinx()

sns.barplot(x=dfg.index.get_level_values('report_date'),
            y=dfg.Head_Count,
           hue=dfg.index.get_level_values('shift'), ax=ax, alpha=0.7)

sns.lineplot(x=dfg.index.get_level_values('report_date'),
            y=dfg.UTL_R,
           hue=dfg.index.get_level_values('shift'), ax=ax2, marker='o', legend=None)

ax.set_title('My Graph')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

**EDIT #2**

Here is the graph as you requested in a second time (stacked, but stack n+1 does not start where stack n ends).

It is slightly more involving as we have to do multiple things:
 - we need to manually assign our color to our `shift` in our df
 - once we have our colors assign, we will iterate through each date range and 1) sort or `Head_Count` values descending (so that our largest sack is in the back when we plot the graph), and 2) plot the data and assign the color to each stacj
 - Then we can create our second y axis and plot our `UTL_R` values
 - Then we need to assign the correct color to our legend labels

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def assignColor(shift):
    if shift == 'A':
        return 'R'
    if shift == '1':
        return 'B'
    if shift == '2':
        return 'G'
    if shift == '3':
        return 'Y'

# map a color to a shift
df['color'] = df['shift'].apply(assignColor)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,6))

# plot our Head_Count values
for date in df.report_date.unique():
    d = df[df.report_date == date].sort_values(by='Head_Count', ascending=False)
    y = d.Head_Count.values
    x = date
    color = d.color
    b = plt.bar(x,y, color=color)

# Plot our UTL_R values
ax2 = ax.twinx()    

sns.lineplot(x=df.report_date, y=df.UTL_R, hue=df['shift'], marker='o', legend=None)

# Assign the color label color to our legend
leg = ax.legend(labels=df['shift'].unique(), loc=1)

legend_maping = dict()

for shift in df['shift'].unique():
    legend_maping[shift] = df[df['shift'] == shift].color.unique()[0]

i = 0
for leg_lab in leg.texts:
    leg.legendHandles[i].set_color(legend_maping[leg_lab.get_text()])
    i += 1
```

[image]

Comment: That unstacked chart is exactly what I wanted to do when I started. Now, is there anyway that the bars could be "on top" of each other but not stacked? The graph picture example i posted has the bars layered on top of each other, but they are not stacked. It looks much cleaner that way. Is it possible?

Comment: @ricsilo, I am unsure if that type of graph would be the most representative of the value, since the reader would have to disipher if the value represented by a stack is the top the stack or the width of the stack. 

For you specific problem, an unstacked graph seems the most appropriate. Though, if you wanted to go the stacked route, you could use a 100% stacked graph.

Comment: I do undertsand the values in the 100% stacked graph will not be accurate (since A represents 100% of the shift). Though, from your data it deos not seem to be the case (i.e. `3/17/2019` `A=72`, but `1+2+3 = 58`. Anyways, I added the code for you to seem how you can create it - if you ever need it.

Comment: So if it's a stacked 100%, is there a way i can multiply the ratio by the value of A, so instead of 0 -1, the values would be 0 -80 (or whatever the headcount is)? And, good point, but the data I provided was randomized as to not provide the private data. I understand it doesn't stack up, but the real data does....

Comment: That makes sense. I made a quick update to exclude the `A` shift from the 100% stacked graph and only show the actual shifts (which should add up to 100% on your real data).

Comment: It seems like the graph i initially had and made by mistake through trial and error has them stacked "over" but not "on top" of each other. Notice the tallest bar peak reaches 80, and if you look where the other bars fall, the sum of those three = aproximately 80. The Bars seem to be overlayed on top of each other. If their colors could be representative of the shifts, it would literally be the perfect solution for me. They're basically the side by side bar solution you provided, but on each other with opacity. It's cleaner and you can still see quantity of heads per shift

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! I was also looking into a solution utilizing c=df['color'].apply(lambda x: colors[x] by mapping a color column from shift and applying that.

Comment: Awesome, do forget to mark the issue as solved so people with similar issue can find it. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
tm_daily_df['UTL_R'] = tm_daily_df['UTL_R'].str.replace('%', '').astype('float') / 100
pivoted = tm_daily_df.pivot_table(values=['Head_Count', 'UTL_R'], 
                                  index='report_date', 
                                  columns='shift')
pivoted

#             Head_Count             UTL_R
# shift                1   2   3   A     1     2     3     A
# report_date
# 3/17/19             11  27  18  72  0.10  0.13  0.25  0.25
# 3/18/19             23  16  12  71  1.00  0.25  0.50  0.10
# 3/19/19             28  23  14  76  0.10  0.50  0.33  0.20
# 3/20/19             29  29  10  59  0.25  0.25  0.50  0.33
# 3/21/19             17  29  30  65  0.20  0.14  0.17  0.10
# 3/22/19             12  10  17  54  0.14  1.00  0.14  0.20
# 3/23/19             16  11  13  66  0.10  1.00  0.10  0.14

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pivoted['Head_Count'].plot.bar(ax=ax)
pivoted['UTL_R'].plot.line(ax=ax, legend=False, secondary_y=True, marker='D')
ax.legend(loc='upper left', title='shift')
```

[image]